# Accessing state in useCallback always returns initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working with Flashlist in React Native and have wrapped my `renderItem` function in a `useCallback` hook. In my component, I have a state (an array) called `todos` and when logging `todos.length`, I simply get the initial state value, 0. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  // Some code omitted for brevity.
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<Todo>) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ height: 50 }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(todos.length); // Always logs 0.
          if (todos.length >= 10) return;
          setTodos((curr) => [item.name, ...curr]);
        }}
      >
        <Heading color={"black"}>{item.name}</Heading>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <FlashList<Todo>
      data={data?.todos as Todo[]}
      estimatedItemSize={50}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(_, idx) => idx.toString()}
    />
  );
}
```

NOTE: I have tried passing both `todos` and `todos.length` to `useCallback` as dependency but received the same result.

Happy to clarify any questions.

Comment: Pass the state as a dependency in the useCallback

Comment: @Lokkesh Passing `todos` as a dependency still logs 0.

Comment: Have you logged the item props?

Comment: @Lokkesh What do you mean?

Comment: The props you are passing to the useCallback

Comment: Why have you used the callback anyway, what do you think it will help with?.  The reason you get current state is that your have a closure on `todos`..   Your `setTodos((curr) =>` is there to avoid that, so place your checks in the callback here..  eg.  `setTodos((curr) => curr.length >= 10 ? curr : [item.name, ...curr]);`

Comment: @Keith Didn't think of making the check in `setTodos` - thanks for pointing that out! Works like a charm now. Would you care to elaborate a bit more on the closure on `todos`?

Comment: `const [todos, ` <--- this will always be `useState` initial state, because your `useCallback` is only ever called once, so even if state changes, it will still be pointing at the first `const [todos, `...   But you could really simplify all of this, just move your Item code into another function and avoid `useCallback` altogether.   eg..   `function Item(....) {/*item code here*/};  export default function MyComponent() {  -> now use Item`   Sub dividing React components, has many benefits, try and avoid doing everything in 1 single component..

Comment: @Keith I understand, but how come adding `todos` as a dependency to `useCallback` didn't work either? And yep, usually do some quick scribbling before moving it to a separate component!

Comment: I would expect adding `todos` to the dependency would solve this too, are you able to knock up a runnable snippet showing this?.   Just a heads-up, splitting into separate components is more than just a re-factor, there are massive performance benefits in doing it too, so if you can get into the habbit of creating the component from sub-components from the start, it gets way easier and more perform-ant..

Comment: @Keith Just tried with a small React example. Added `todos` as a dependency and it worked. Not quite sure why it didn't have any effect when I tried with Flashlist... Regardless, thanks for all the help! If you want to put together an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

and

```
const renderItem = useCallback(
  () => {
    //todo's here is a closure, it will not update
    //a dependency of [] means, just run once.
  },
  []
);
```

This is a common issue to hit, as it's not obvious.  Because this can happen often `setState` has a callback version.  In your code your actually using this to set the state, but you will also need to use this to get the current state for doing your max 10 check.

So a simple fix is to place your length check inside the useState callback.

```
setTodos((curr) => curr.length >= 10 ? curr : [item.name, ...curr]);
```

In the above if the current length is greater or equal to 10, just return current state, otherwise add the new item.

Another option, is of course to add, todos to the useCallback state, but why this is not working with `FlashList`, not sure.

An even better option, is extract the `Item` into another sub-component.  There are other benefits to doing this, like more composability, code sharing, and best of all performance.